# What is the best way to delete and create new related entity in ef core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have ef core entity which has related entity.

```
public sealed class MyEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; init; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int? Age { get; set; }

    public RelatadEntity? RelatadEntity { get; set; }
}
```

And I have code for it's updating.

```
public async Task Update(Guid id, UpdateEntity update)
{
    var entity = (await context.TableA.FindAsync(id))!;
    var entityFromModel = mapper.Map<MyEntity>(update);

    entity.Description = entityFromModel.Description;
    entity.Age = entityFromModel.Age;
        
    if (entity.RelatedEntity is not null)
        context.TableB.Remove(entity.RelatedEntity);
    entity.RelatedEntity = entityFromModel.RelatedEntity is not null ? (await context.TableB.AddAsync(entityFromModel.RelatedEntity)).Entity : null;
        
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Code deletes previos related entity if exists, creates a new one and updates it. But this takes too much code. Is there any way to make it simpler? I'm not really good at ef core and don't know if there are any ways.

Maybe I can use context.Update(newEntity) and make it auto-recreate related entities?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
public async Task Update(Guid id, UpdateEntity update)
{
    var entity = await context.TableA.Include(e => e.RelatedEntity).FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);

    if (entity == null)
    {
        // Handle entity not found error
    }

    mapper.Map(update, entity);

    if (update.RelatedEntity != null)
    {
        if (entity.RelatedEntity == null)
        {
            entity.RelatedEntity = update.RelatedEntity;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Entry(entity.RelatedEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(update.RelatedEntity);
        }
    }
    else if (entity.RelatedEntity != null)
    {
        context.TableB.Remove(entity.RelatedEntity);
    }

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Hope it's help